# I want to render the data with the HTML file

Tags: node.js

```
routes.get('/agents',function(req,res,next){
    var sess = req.session;
    var userData = sess.username;
    console.log("Data is coming here  "+userData);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/agents.html',[{"sessionData":userData}]);
});
```

I want to send the data with the file and use the data in html file.
Any way to do this.Please let me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a templating engine to render your data. [EJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) and [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) work great and are quite popular, you'll find plenty of resource to learn how to use it. [LearnJade](http://www.learnjade.com/) is a good one to learn.

Using Jade :

```
routes.get('/agents', function(req, res, next) {
    var sess = req.session;
    var userData = sess.username;
    console.log("Data is coming here  " + userData);
    res.render("agents.jade", {"sessionData": userData, "doesItWork": "yeah"});
});
```

Comment: Can you explain me the scenario in which you will use this route ?
If it's an auth page, you should post your credentials to the server which will respond with the user data

Comment: there is a authentication page with url /auth where i m checking credentials .. and i want to open agent.html with the url /agents and the session data.If there is any way to access session object in html page please let me know. I want to add some more data to session in the html page.